# Mocking interfaces that have 'new' members with Moq

Tags: c#, moq

I'm having problems mocking an set of interfaces:

```
interface IFoo
{
    object Blah { get; }
}

interface IBar : IFoo
{
    new string Blah { get; }
}
```

I tried mocking as:

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
mock.SetupGet(m => m.Blah).Returns("Blah");
```

This works now:

```
Assert.That(mock.Object.Blah, Is.EqualTo("Blah"));
```

The problem is that when I add the following, to also have a value for the `IBar` interface, the value of `IFoo.Blah` is null.

```
var bar = mock.As<IBar>();
bar.SetupGet(m => m.Blah).Returns("Blah");
```

This works now:

```
Assert.That(((IBar)mock.Object).Blah, Is.EqualTo("Blah"));
```

But the old one fails:

```
Assert.That(mock.Object.Blah, Is.EqualTo("Blah"));
// mock.Object.Blah is null now
```

Is there a way to get both to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MOQ  (v4.0.10827) and .Net 4, this code is working:

```
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
var bar = mock.As<IBar>();
mock.SetupGet(m => m.Blah).Returns("Blah");
Assert.That(mock.Object.Blah, Is.EqualTo("Blah"));
bar.SetupGet(m => m.Blah).Returns("BlahBlah");
Assert.That(((IBar)mock.Object).Blah, Is.EqualTo("BlahBlah"));
Assert.That(mock.Object.Blah, Is.EqualTo("Blah"));
```

You must initialize your interface before setting up your property.

Comment: It seems that putting the `mock.As<IBar>` up higher helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use "override" instead of "new". When you use "new", you're actually making a second function. Here's the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx

Comment: Unless the additional function is intended, in which case you'd need to find a way to mock both functions when you use IBar.

Comment: I can't use override, because one of the interfaces, `IFoo` in this case, is not mine. I need to mock both functions, but mocking the second one clears the mock for the first one